# Azure SQL reporting on last READ records

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is it possible to generate a report from Azure MS SQL Server which shows which records in a table were last read from?

We have a table which we would like to begin cleaning records out of and it would be useful to know which data it contains that is no longer used by the client application. Unfortunately, it does not contain a datetime field which shows when the records were last accessed.

Comment: No, it is not a feature.  You would generate a ton of log doing reads to update a timestamp and kill performance of the database to do this.  There is a temporal table feature which gives you lifetimes for values within a table, keeping older versions of a row.  That's about as close as you'd get.

Comment: Submit that as an answer and win a tick!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a feature in SQL Server.  The reason is that it would make the database a lot slower if we turned every read into a write.  Since we have to log everything, we'd generate tons of log write traffic.  There is a feature called Temporal Tables which doesn't quite do what you ask but it does have start/end dates for rows.  You could track when you don't want to see a row anymore and then it would go into the history table.  You can then remove rows from the history table after some period of non-use.  The retention feature can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and you can read a conceptual overview of temporal tables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)